# How do I make a selection from a dropdown list in python without using selenium

Tags: python, drop-down-menu, web-scraping

new to python!

I've navigated to a webpage using the requests package and used a set of defined cookies

```
cookies = {[insert cookies here]}
url = "[http://myurl.net]"
page = requests.get(url, cookies=cookies).content
```

if the html for the dropdown menu is below, how would i select the menu item titled "FULTON" without using selenium

```
<div style="margin-bottom:10px;"><b>County:</b> <select 
id="BodyContent_ddlCounties" name="ctl00$BodyContent$ddlCounties" 
style="width:150px;border: 1px solid #666666;">
<option value="-1">All Counties</option>
<option value="1">APPLING</option>
<option value="2">ATKINSON</option>
<option value="3">BACON</option>
<option value="4">BAKER</option>
<option value="5">BALDWIN</option>
<option value="6">FULTON</option>
</select></div>
```

thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Given the content, you can try this:

```
page = requests.get(url, cookies=cookies).content
content = [i.text for i in page.find_all('option')][1:]
```

Output:

```
['APPLING', 'ATKINSON', 'BACON', 'BAKER', 'BALDWIN', 'FULTON']
```